# Наложение картинок, g2d

Tags: java, графика, java2d

Рисую одну картинку на другой, но она рисуется влоб
[image: пример до]
Мне же нужно, что бы пиксели накладываемой картинки имели ту же прозрачность, что и пиксели первой, должно выйти что то такое
[image: пример после]
Пытался прогонять пиксели каждой картинки, задавая пикселям накладываемой прозрачность основной, но не пошло, и вся картинка была тупо синей, текущий код выглядит так

```java
public static ByteBuffer uniteTextures(String mainTexture, String secondTexture) {
        BufferedImage mergedImage = BufferedImageEncoder(mainTexture);
        Graphics2D g2d = mergedImage.createGraphics();

        g2d.drawImage(BufferedImageEncoder(secondTexture), 0, 0, null);
        g2d.dispose();

        return ByteBufferEncoder(mergedImage);
    }
```